# Fullcalendar layout broken because CSS loading after javascript layout calculations

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm using the [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) jQuery plugin in an web application framework plugin.

Additional CSS files like the fullcalendar.css are loaded dynamically in javascript:

```
$("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar.css' />").appendTo("head");
```

The fullcalendar.js renders (and positions) calendar events. The positions are calculated wrong if the fullcalendar.css file is not yet loaded at that point, and "moved" offscreen after the CSS is loaded.

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/peter_/gy6nk4a5/)

How can I avoid this?
Is it a problem in fullcalendar?

Edit: I found the `$(window).load()` event. It ''seems'' that if I move the JS call to initialize fullcalendar in there, the problem disappears. It this a bad idea?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're loading the CSS dynamically? Seems like the easy solution would be static loading in `head`.

Comment: Yes, because it's an application framework plugin. It is only activated later, creating the head has already long finished by then.

Comment: Are you able to insert your FullCalendar JS _after_ you add the css using `appendTo`?

Comment: The appendTo happens first, but takes longer for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to defer the loading of your `fullCalendar` script until after the CSS file is appended to the head tag:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/gy6nk4a5/3/)

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {

    $("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar.css' />").appendTo("head");

    $(window).on("load", function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Should be June 1!',
                    start: '2014-06-01'
                },
            ]
        });        
    });    
});
```

In this case, the CSS file is appended when the DOM is ready, but your script fires when the DOM has finished loading.

An alternate method would be to use jQuery's `holdReady()` method which is designed specifically for script loading:

### [holdReady();](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/)

```
$.holdReady( true );

// do something and when ready...

$.holdReady( false );
```

Comment: I'm using the $(window).load() for now, that seems to be equivalent to you first method so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: holdReady() looks interesting. But where would I call holdReady(false) in this specific case?

Comment: @Peter You would set `holdReady(true);` then you would have to use `setInterval()` and check if a property from that CSS file has been applied to an element every 50ms or so. If the element _has_ that property, you can set `holdReady(false)` and then `clearInterval()`. It's a fairly long winded way compared with the load method which is why I suggested it as an alternate.

Another way you could perhaps do it (although not tested) would be to append your CSS file in the head but add your calendar script to a script tag as the last element on the page before closing the body tag.